# ActionMailer doesn't recognise route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actionmailer

I have a route called "settings_redirect", which I've defined as follows:

**routes.rb**

```
match "/settings/redirect" => "settings#redirect", :via => "get"
```

I want to link to this route in an email template:

**mymail.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Manage Settings", settings_redirect_url %>
```

Yet, when I get ActionMailer to send the email, I get the error

```
{undefined local variable or method `settings_redirect_url' for #<#:0x007ffa1153de38>
```

The same link works completely fine in any regular view, just not when I try to send it in an email. All other links in the same template don't cause any trouble either.

Any ideas as to what could cause the error?

Comment: Are you calling the 'settings_redirect_url' in your view template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
match "/settings_redirect" => "settings#redirect", :via => "get"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this form:

```
get "settings/redirect" => "settings#redirect", :as => :settings_redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views